# Exp-resso Store Shipping Select auto refresh

Tags: expresso-store, javascript, jquery

Can't seem to find an answer in the documentation, not sure a feature is even needed for this (might just need JS). Can't seem to figure it out though.

I'm using `{field:shipping_method}` to generate a select dropdown for shipping options. I'd like the total to update after a new shipping method is selected. How can I do this?

Right now I'm using:

```
$('#shipping_method').change(function(){
        location.reload();       
 });
```

To reload the page but it's not retaining the information. It resets to default shipping option.

Comment: You probably need to have your JavaScript actually submit the form rather than reload the page.

Comment: Yeah I just figured this, but the solutions I'm finding modify the <select> tag, which is being automatically generated by the Store. Would it be best to use JS to add the onchange function after the page loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if the markup is entirely correct, but this works:

```
$("#shipping_method").change(function(e) {
    $(this.form).submit();
});
```

Comment: Just edited to make the jquery a little easier to read :)